# Keycloak Authorization Code flow (Encrypting + reusable)

Tags: authentication, security, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect

I want an answer to two questions.

1. Using the redirect based strategy in keylock, for authorization, I redirect the user to the address:

> https://keycloakhost/auth/realms/realm-name/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=some-application&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://redirectHost

Can I use some kind of encryption for the parameters

> ?client_id=some-application&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://redirectHost

In order not to transfer them in the clear (well, it would be nice to get the effect of shortening the link).

2. How can you implement the possibility that two different clients with the same client_scope would be able to allow users from another client into the system?